# Uint16Array is undefined error while using pdfmake.js in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdfmake

I am getting the below error while using the pdfmake.js, In my test work i dont have any error and I am geting my expected output. but in my original page I am using jqploat chart js,sumoselect.min.js and bootstrap-multiselect.js as extra.

Unhandled exception at line 2, column 107163 in http://localhost:59691/Scripts/plugins/pdfmake.min.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Uint16Array' is undefined

Comment: What are you trying to convert to a PDF? Are there different errors? In a non-local environment there can be different security rules like CORS and reading files from the local disk that might be causing something else to fail which in turn is showing this error.

Comment: @lemieuxster I am trying to convert the chart generated by jqploat. In page loading time itself I am geting this error. Only this error I am getting

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: And are you using Uint16Array directly? If so it might be useful to see some code.

Comment: @lemieuxster I am using IE 11. I am not using Uint16Array , its there in the pluggin, I am getting the error from pdfmakejs